# Exactly for what am I billed in Facebook Pages Ad campaign?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, ads

I have run a 3-days long Facebook Pages Ad campaign and by the end of third day Facebook said:

[image]

For exactly what am I billed? Did I spent `33.59 PLN` (~11 USD) for reaching `1,785` viewers (about 160 viewers / reachers per 1 PLN) or for likes (~3.5 like per 1 USD)?

Answer to this question is essential to me. I've received 39 likes in total for 3-days campaign, that costed me 11 USD. While Facebook promised me at least 50 likes per day for $5 (daily budged set by me) -- cite: "est. 50-200 likes per day". So, if I'm counted for likes, not for impressions (reach) that would mean that this Facebook Page Ad campaign ended up as a complete failure and money waste.

**Edit**: *I used the very basic version of ad, by clicking `Promote Page` and setting campaign length (set to 3 days) and daily budget (set to $5 / 16 PLN).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [Ads Manager](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/) section, for a simple, basic campaign created with `Promote Page` buton in Facebook, you can see detailed information about all your ads campaigns.

Second column there says `Cost $0.32 Page Likes`, which may lead us to a conclusion, that you're paying for each new Like to your page, marked as `Paid` (so, excluding those marked as `Organic`).

If you hover your mouse on `?` sign next to `Cost`, you'll see an explanation saying: `The average you paid for each action associated with your objective`. Which -- in my opinion -- is confirming my above asumption.

Answer (score 1):

When you set your Facebook ads for Page likes you see the following at the bottom

> Your bid will be optimized to get more Page likes. You will be charged every time someone is shown your ad.

So you are being charged for whoever saw your ad. Checking what your bid is set at should give you a better idea. There is no real promise of accurate likes, only an estimate. The real thing you are paying for is a bid on the ad space.

Also, impressions and reach are not quite the same. Reach is the number of *unique* viewers.

I don't mean this in a bad way, but if the campaign failed it's partly your fault as well in the execution of your campaign. If for example, your targeting and audience are not in line with your page, then you aren't going to get the results you want.

My suggestions

- stop the campaign
- start over from scratch
- check your expectations to within correct constraints
- look up previous similar cases on the web to see how the bid matches up
- actively fine tune the campaign as you move along

(If it were as simple as clicking a few buttons and letting the ads run on automatic then everyone would have likes all the time...)

Also look into these pages

- https://www.facebook.com/business
- https://www.facebook.com/marketing

There are case studies, solutions and videos available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You're talking about advanced ad scheme, build with advanced ad tool (where you set the bid, and for what you want to be billed -- impressions or clicks). I **didn't** use that yet. I used the very basic version of ad, by clicking `Promote Page` and setting daily budget only. So, I think your answer mismatches my question, or what I did, a little bit, as the only factors, I was controlling, was ad campaign length (set to 3 days) and daily budget (set to $5 / 16 PLN). Sorry, for not clearing that out in the question...